# How to work with imbalance data in python?

Tags: python

I have a dataset of 3500 rows and 113 columns, the output feature is categorical that I want to predict by random forest, all the input features are numerical. But the problem is that the output feature containing BAD and GOOD as a category, the ratio of GOOD to BAD is 30 or more, I am a new boy in the field of python. How to proceed?

Comment: Include the package you are using (presumably pandas). What you've tried, and some example code. At this point we're only guessing.

Comment: As you have not shown the code, i can also only answer in pseudocode

The simplest way for you to achieve that would be to:
1. split the data into the train and test datasets
2. split the train data into categories
3. get a random sample of length len(BAD), assuming BAD is smaller, from GOOD part and join them together.

Comment: I would say the question is a better fit on stats.stackexchange. Your problem isn't programming related per-se; It's rather asking for advice / strategy to working with imbalance data (generally speaking)

Comment: I used pandas to read csv files, split the data into train and test, used random forest classifier as below.

classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 200, random_state = 0, class_weight = "balanced")
classifier.fit(x_train,y_train)
y_prediction = classifier.predict(x_test)

Still not able to predict a single 1, though 0 are predicted well as they are the majority.

What should be done now?
There are about 3200 numbers of zeros and only 100 numbers of ones.

Answer (score 0):

Since `train_test_split` splits the `df` based on a random factor `random_state`, my favorite method to get a good representing split is to check the result of the split for different `random_state`, and than choose the one that spilts the data in the closest to reality way. So assuming that `df['target']` has the 0 and 1 values for the target:

```
target_mean = df['target'].mean()
rs_best = 0
min_difference = 1
for rs in range(50):
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df.drop('target', axis=1), df['target'], test_size=0.25, random_state=rs)
    cur_difference = abs(y_train.mean() - target_mean) 
    if cur_difference < min_difference:
        rs_best, min_difference = rs, cur_difference
print('Best random state split:', rs_best, min_difference)
```

And then you can use the best `random_state` value for the real split for your model:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df.drop('target', axis=1), df['target'], test_size=0.25, random_state=)
```